# smart android T.V box

Tags: java, android, android-tv

Can I ask some help. we have smart android T.V box and already set up. we have 20 T.V channels set up. Now we want to create an android application that can select channel and display it to the screen just like the other cable provider that they have menu or list of their channels and you can select each of them to view on screen.The android app is installed in our smart android T.V box.

I have this simple running code but the problem is that I cannot show it again the list of my channels in order to select other channel I need to press the back button in order to show the list (discouraging I use listview). how can I achieve just like the same other cable provider that they can show the menu of channels on the left side and only will show if they press the menu.

this is what I have so far.

MyActivity.class

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        String[] values = new String[] { "Nickelodeon", "Animal Planet", "CNN",
                "MTV", "History Channel", "Discovery Channel", "National Geographic Wild", "MovieMAX HD",
                "Science Channel", "TLC" };


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.videolist,R.id.label,values);

          setListAdapter(adapter);
     }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayVid.class);
        intent.putExtra("channelextra", item);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Showvideo.class

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String url = "url chanell here"; // static for my demo purpose only


        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
        mediacontroller = new MediaController(this);
        mediacontroller.setMediaPlayer(video);
        video.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        video.requestFocus();
        video.start();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String item = extras.getString("channelextra");


    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you are asking about this http://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/now-playing.html or something else. Some screenshots might help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: yes something like that but how do I put my t.v channels ? thank you in advance.

Comment: If you have your own TV channels then have you seen this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/index.html

Comment: Aftr changeing chanel you are staying at Showvideo.class. In your Showvideo.class you have not the listview with chanels.

Comment: @MorrisonChang is there video tutorial on this ? so that i can understand more,I was not able to understand the documentation of androids. thank you in advance